# Dynamically created table via XHR is not displayed in whole

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am using jquery to load asynchronous a HTML table and append that on an existing div element.
That works fine!

But if the content of the HTML table is very large then my table is truncated by the length of my browser window and I have no possibility to scroll down to the end of my table.

Has anybody an idea how can I solve this problem.

Many thanks
Tasso

```
var root=document.getElementById('tabPrNr');

var tab=document.createElement('table');
tab.className="mytable";
var tbo=document.createElement('tbody');
var row, cell;

for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
    row=document.createElement('tr');
     for(var j=0;j<5;j++){
      cell=document.createElement('td');
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i+' '+j))
      row.appendChild(cell);
     }
tbo.appendChild(row);
}
tab.appendChild(tbo);
root.appendChild(tab);
```

Comment: care to show your code??

Comment: You need to elaborate with a source code, CSS, HTML, etc...